# Use form handle in a vb.net class without pass it as argument?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, class, handle

I'm writting a class that needs the form handle but there is a way to use it without send it as argument in the class constructor or in a property?

I know that the handler is not set until the form is completely loaded so that is another problem too.

The basic idea is catch the form handle without pass it as argument and handle the wm messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution that fit my needs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.createhandle.aspx

This allows me to create a "ghost window" and get the handler of it in the runtime without modify my class or pass the handler in the constructor or a property.

Other thing that was needing was handle the WM's and this solves the problem too.

Be aware that the WM and the form handler are of the "ghost window", not of the form that host the interface.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what do you mean for 'Form Handle' (The form object itself or the Form.Handle property?).

However, you could use the **My.Application.OpenForms** collection [(see here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eh13dca9.aspx) to loop on all the open forms and find the one you require knowing its Title or Name

```
Private Function GetFormByTitle(title as String) as Form
    Dim result As Form
    For Each f As Form In My.Application.OpenForms
        if f.Text = title then
            result = f
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

you could then use the result of this method to grab the 'handle' of the identified form:

```
Dim h as IntPtr
Dim f as Form

f = GetFormByTitle("Caption_Of_Form")
if f IsNot Nothing then
    h = f.Handle
    ' .... do your work with handle here
End if
```

Comment: +1: The [NUnitForms](http://nunitforms.sourceforge.net/) project uses what you said to let you access forms by their name or title. It's open source, so you can get the code from there.

Comment: No, i need to pass the form handle. "Me.Handle" Thats host the internal identifier of the form that later allows me to catch the window messages. (internal messages of the os). Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx but that is for controls but it's the same principle.

Comment: @SeinOxygen then grab the result from the method above and use that handle. See the updated answer

Comment: So i should modify the clas o ver and over again if i reuse it in other forms?... that's not practical at all.